# Undocking a ToolStrip from a ToolStripPanel

Tags: .net, winforms, toolstrip, toolstrippanel

Out of the box, there doesn't appear to be any built-in support for allowing your end-users to undock the `ToolStrip`s in your applications from their parent `ToolStripPanel`s.  Clearly it's possible because even your Visual Studio IDE allows you to undock/tear-off/float your tool strips, it's just isn't possible with the default behavior of the `ToolStrip` and `ToolStripPanel`.

So, does anyone have an advice?  I'd like to allow our end users to be able to tear-off `ToolStrip`s, and have them float freely wherever they'd like them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem like there's much around to do this.

There's a CodeProject article [A Simple C# Toolbar Docking Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/ToolBarDock.aspx), that looks to be a more light-weight option than DockPanel suite.

Comment: Nice.  Thanks for the link.  This looks promising.  If something else doesn't pop up, I'm thinking this is the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I would look into the [DockPanel suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/). It's not really emulating Visual Studio's Toolstrip functionality so much as its floating/dockable windows, but it does handle docking and tearing like a champ.

Comment: +1 for mentioning DockPanel suite as it's an excellent toolkit. We actually use the DockPanel suite for our form docking/floating purposes, and it had occurred to me that one could emulate the behavior floating toolbar behavior using the DPS.  I was hoping to find something that was less of a hack, however.